# Proof involving homomorphism - Abstract Algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra

I will greatly appreciate details here.

**Theorem:**

Let $\phi: G \to H$ be a group homomorphism: 
    - $$\text{if}\space\space L \leq H, \space\space \text{then} \space\space \phi^{-1}(L) \leq G $$
     $$\text{if} \space\space L \mathrel{\unlhd} H \space \space  \text{then}\space \space \phi^{-1}( L) \mathrel{\unlhd} G$$

For the first part:

I know that $L$ a subgroup of $H$ means that every element in $L$ is also an element of $H$. Then since $\phi$ maps from $G$ to $H$, the inverse image of an element in $H$ must live within $G$. And so the inverse image of elements in $L$ must live in $G$ also. I am not sure how to prove the preservation of group properties etc. Just case-by-case for closure, inverses etc.?

For the second part - the same thing.

Comment: If a subset of a group is closed wrt the group operation and taking inverses, then it is a subgroup...

Answer (score 1):

For example:

$$g_1,g_2\in\phi^{-1}(L)\implies \phi(g_i)\in L\stackrel{\text{since}\;L\le K}\implies \phi(g_1)\phi(g_2)\stackrel{\text{hom.}}=\phi(g_1g_2)\in L\implies g_1g_2\in\phi^{-1}(L)$$

and we have closure.

Try the other ones: are very similar to the above.

Comment: Okay - that was actually a good hint on how to think through the others. I will type up an outline of a proof shortly for you all to look over!  Thanks.

Comment: @ Timbuc - I have a full proof for the first part of this. For the second, I know I need to show left and right cosets are equal. Could you perhaps give a hint on this? I know most of the equivalent forms of gh=hg for all g in G and h in H so I can manipluate that to work with a more usable expression here.  I'm just a bit lost on what to do in this particular case.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, I don't think there's a quick way to do it all at once.  Basically, if $x,y \in \phi ^{-1} (L)$ then $\phi(x) = a, \phi(y) = b$ for some $a,b \in L$.  Then $\phi(xy) = \phi(x)\phi(y) = ab \in L$, so $xy \in \phi^{-1}(ab) \subset \phi^{-1}(L)$.

For inverses, since $L \ni 1 = \phi(x)\phi(x^{-1})$, then  $\phi(x^{-1}) = \phi(x)^{-1} \in L$ and so $x^{-1} \in \phi^{-1}(L)$

All the rest go sort of like that too.